# POSIX Queue Message Using fork() function

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I am trying to create 2 processes ( client and server) through the fork() function and using the POSIX message queue to exchange messages. When I compile the client and server separately I have no issues and I get the results that I want. However, when I try to combine both the client and the server in the main function I get an error and nothing compiles. I am not sure if it's even possible to use fork() and POSIX message queue together in the main function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MQ_NAME "/mq_cola_queue"

typedef struct {
    char msg[80];
}Message;


__pid_t wait();

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    


    int id = fork();

    // parent process (server)
    if (id == 0) {

        struct mq_attr attributes = {
                .mq_flags = 0,
                .mq_maxmsg = 10,
                .mq_curmsgs = 0,
                .mq_msgsize = sizeof (Message)

        };

        printf("Hello from parent.\n");
        wait(1);


        mqd_t queue = mq_open(MQ_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, &attributes);

        Message msg;
        mq_receive(queue, (char *)&msg , sizeof(msg), NULL);



        mq_close(queue);
        mq_unlink(MQ_NAME);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

        


   // child process (client)
    } else {


        struct mq_attr attributes = {
                .mq_flags = 0,
                .mq_maxmsg = 10,
                .mq_curmsgs = 0,
                .mq_msgsize = sizeof (Message)

        };
        printf("Hello from child.\n");

        mqd_t queue = mq_open(MQ_NAME, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, &attributes);

        Message msg;
        strcpy(msg.msg, "This is my first message.\n");

        mq_send(queue, (char *)&msg, sizeof (msg), 1);
        /* wait for input to end the program */
        fprintf(stdout, "Press any key to finish\n");
        getchar();

        mq_close(queue);
        mq_unlink(MQ_NAME);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tangential style issue: Don't write declarations like `__pid_t wait();` in your code.  Use the proper header — in this case, that's `#include <sys/wait.h>`.  The return type you use is an internal name; the correct type to use is `pid_t` (`extern pid_t wait(int *status);` if you must write it out, but you don't need to do that — you should use the header instead).  Note too that your invocation `wait(1);` is likely to cause a crash.

Comment: You don't explain the error you get.  You should.  You should include the error message from the code you post in the question.  There is no reason why you can't use `fork()` — so the problem is fixable once we know what it is.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! it worked after I removed the __pid_t wai();

Comment: `wai` --> `wait` in your comment, if you're quick.